# Are the terms corner frequency,cutoff frequency and break frequency the same?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, frequency, cutoff-frequency

I am studying electronics engineering and I came across these terms..how are these terms different from each other?

Comment: In general they are the same, but to be precise you can for example refer to the -3dB frequency since some of the terms can have different meanings in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all loose terms used to describe filters or coupling networks, often it is the -3dB point that is being referred to, but not always.

With a single pole RC filter, the -3dB point is convenient as its frequency drops straight out of the sums for the RC time constant.

With a Butterworth filter, regardless of the order, the cnventional edge of the passband is at -3dB, and called a cutoff or corner frequency.

Be aware that filters have 'interesting' frequencies in other places, the edge of a Chebychev the passband is often specified at 1dB or 0.1dB, the edge of the stopband at possibly -60dB, which are sometimes casually referred to as cutoff, corner or break frequencies. When in doubt, check the context.

Comment: Worth noting that you should never rely on these terms to make comparison between specifications - always use accurately defined parameters which are relevant to the application - commercial filters rarely match the classical response curves precisely.